# Authenticate ApEx application without password

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I have forms application and APEX application, I am looking for a solution, where, a button in forms is pressed, it launches apex application and authenticates it without need for password. Please help me with a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the approach here http://www.oracle-and-apex.com/authenticate-apex-via-token/ made some changes as per my needs. We can encrypt the token if needed.

Answer (score 0):

That would be *no authentication*. In order to do that, in Apex:

- go to application's Shared Components
- for Security, click Authentication Schemes
- create a new scheme, based on a pre-configured scheme from the gallery
- provide its name and select **No authentication** from the select list

Once you're done, it will be a *current* authentication scheme so - when you navigate to its URL - the page will open, without asking for credentials.

Comment: Hi little foot I am not saying no authentication sorry if my question gave the impression like that. I am looking for a solution like authentication with a token embedded in url, rather making user to enable to enter password. Like single sign on..but not using SSO.

Comment: Aha. Well, if it were two Apex applications, I'd know the answer. Forms + Apex: sorry, I wouldn't know that. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just figured this out, and since I found this page looking for help, maybe some others will find my method and it will help them.  I wish I could post more of my code, but our internal workstations are not on the same network as our outside workstations, so the only way I have to transmit information from one to the other is by typing it all.

This is the method I use, and it does require some way to authenticate your users in the database.  This part might be difficult for you; people in my workplace all have self-signed PKI certificates loaded in our workstations, and we can use the Oracle OWA_UTIL package to read information from them. I suppose an LDAP server could handle this part, but I'm just speculating.  If the plan it to not use a username/password logon, you've got to have some way of authenticating yourself to the app.

So.  First, create a new Authentication Scheme of the type Custom in the Shared Components section.  Give it some name, and then down in the Authentication Function Name box, put in the name of a function you will create that takes the parameters "p_username" and "p_password", and returns a boolean.  I use this to check just the most basic permissions, like to be on the network at all.

The odd thing about this section is that it just really seems to want only the name without the parameters.  What I mean is that if your function is built like "authenticateUsers(p_username IN varchar2, p_password IN varchar2)" and returns a boolean, you will enter it in this section just as "authenticateUsers".  Done.  Just make sure the function actually exists, and takes those exact parameter names and returns a boolean.

Then I create two regions in the Logon page.  Mine are called "Get Authorization Info," (GAI for short) and the other is called "Authentication Unsuccessful." (AU)   This region has a sub-region I call "Welcome," but it's really more of a rejection note.

The GAI region has a style of "display:none" and has several page items of Hidden type, and these gather information about your user for authentication.  This part might be difficult for you, as we all have self-signed PKI certificates loaded in our workstations, and we can use the Oracle OWA_UTIL package to read information from them.  I suppose an LDAP server could handle this part, but I'm just speculating.  One of our page items here is the

The AU region and its sub-region have a style of "display:block", but are kept hidden with the Server-side condition of "item=value" and the item being your main page item in the GAI region that authenticates the user connecting, and the value=false.  If your authentication scheme fails to recognize the user, the AU region is exposed and the Welcome sub-region displays its "Welcome" message.

There is also a dynamic action that runs on page load.  If the authentication is successful, that action submits the page.  Finally, the custom Login runs and moves to the first page of the application.

This is the one we use:

```
wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login(
P_UNAME => :P9999_USERNAME, 
P_PASSWORD => :P9999_PASSWORD,
P_SESSION_ID => v('APP_SESSION'),
P_FLOW_PAGE => :APP_ID||':1'
);
```

To sum it all up, at page load time at the Login page, all the authorization information is gathered... somehow and a determination is made.  The main authentication item is set to TRUE or FALSE.  If FALSE, the hidden sub-region of failure is exposed, and if TRUE, the dynamic action kicks off the custom logon (and it doesn't care at this point if the username or password exists (they don't), and the first page of the app will be displayed, with the username you passed to the custom login in the upper right corner.

Good luck.